# What version of TurboTax to get

Tags: united-states, income-tax, turbotax

Last year I worked on a 1099 Contract for 4 months and a W2 Contract for 6 months. I'm not sure which version of Turbotax to buy. Actually I'm not sure if doing this myself is the best way to go but I'm still looking into that. Thanks

Comment: Related on Software Recommendations: [Which version of TurboTax do I need for a small home-based sales business?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/43/83)

Comment: That answer does cover this question, but, as it's on another stack, I'd keep this one here, not 'close as duplicate'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having more details from you, such as whether you have to file a state tax return, it sounds to me like TurboTax deluxe (with state?) should be fine. 
My taxes are far more complex, 1099 income, W-2 income, investments, retirement withdrawals, and more. Again, in my opinion, for over 90% of situations people can easily work with tax software and handle their own return filing. I mean no disrespect to the professionals, but in many cases it’s simply a matter of you providing every bit of data that they are going to have a data entry clerk input into your tax return.

Last, most tax software comes with a 60 or 90 day refund policy. If you feel it’s not right for you you can return it for a refund. If you are using it and get confused you can return here or to their own message board and ask specific questions.

Comment: To add to this, if you're using TurboTax online it's easy to upgrade if you discover along the way that something you need isn't covered.

Comment: If your goal is to continue as a 1099 employee then it might be best to hire a CPA.  If not turbo tax is good enough.

Comment: Pete, can you elaborate on that, or post a full answer? What makes 1099 income result in a complex return that an individual might struggle with?

Comment: Thanks for the information @JoeTaxpayer. I think I'll give it a try on my own this time and see how it goes.

Comment: My state has an easy and free e-file system, and since my state income tax is based on federal taxable income it takes ~10 minutes to file state, might not be worth it to you, but I don't like paying extra to file my state so I do that through the state site.

Comment: The difference between federal-only and fed/state is minimal ($10-15), and I like how transparent it is, i.e. it all flows and does add even a minute of time to my filing.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD If upsells weren't easy, then Intuit would be doing something wrong :-)